# Function that reads all of the array members from the user in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I need to declare an array(size 10) in main() function and and read all the array elements from user using another function. I tried the code below, but doesn't work. How can I take array elements from user using another function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int A[10];
    readArray(A);

    return 0;
}

void readArray(int *A)
{
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("A[%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d\n", &A[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `but doesn't work`? You never seem to have printed the values.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your code that works as long as users provide numbers and type return immediately after the number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void readArray(int *A)
{
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("A[%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
        getchar();
    }
}

int main()
{
    int A[10];
    readArray(A);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want your code to be more robust by skipping spaces in front and after the number, you will need to read a full input line and then scan the line for the number.

---

EDIT: as requested in the comment, here is another version of the code that will read input as a line, and will extract the first positive or negative number found in the line.

Au you can see, an input line may contain no number. This program will ask again for the number until it gets a line containing a number.

I printed the number stored in A[i] to provide a feedback.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void readArray(int *A)
{
    const int BUFFERSIZE = 2048;
    char line[BUFFERSIZE];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            printf("A[%d]: ", i);
            fgets(line, BUFFERSIZE, stdin);
            // skip non-digits in start of string
            int j = 0;
            while(line[j] != '\0' && !isdigit(line[j]) && !((line[j] == '-') && isdigit(line[j+1])))
                j++;
            if(isdigit(line[j]) || line[j] == '-'){
                A[i] = atoi(&line[j]);
                break;
            }
            printf("input has no number, retry\n");
        }
        printf("A[%d] = %d\n", i, A[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int A[10];
    readArray(A);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code still doesn’t compile on a strict compiler.

Comment: @KonradRudolph it compiles and runs for me. What compilation error do you get ?

Comment: Oh yes, you have to put the definition of the `readArray` function before the definition of the function `main`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/QjezoV

Comment: @KonradRudolph move the definition of the `readArray` function in front of the definition of `main`.

Comment: @chmike, your code is perfectly working. But can you explain what getchar() is actually doing here?

Comment: @ShakilAhmed getchar reads one character from the standard input. It reads the newline character that is not read by the scanf.

Comment: @chmike, in this case, that one character is a space. Am I right?

Comment: A newline character is not a space. It is '\n'. When you type return after the number, the character '\n' is appended to the number. The scanf("%d") reads only the number and not the '\n'. The `getchar()` reads and discards the '\n' character. Without it, the next scanf will find a '\n' in stdIn and not the number. This is what blocked the program.

Comment: @chmike, Thanks man.  how can I read a full input line and then scan the line for the number?

Comment: @ShakilAhmed I edited the answer and added another version of the code that reads a full line and scan for a number in the line. The behavior of the program is undefined if the input line contains more than BUFFERSIZE characters (2048).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check if your code works by printing the array `A` in your `main` by doing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("A[%d]: %d\n", i, A[i]);
```

Comment: It doesn't even ask for user input.

Comment: @ShakilAhmed Doesn't it ask for input from stdin with scanf?